# how to find a sub string in a line from a text file and print the particular line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file like this:

```
[739:246050] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
[739:247021] PHYThrad: DSPMsgQ  Received: msg type is[130] and SFNSF [14997] [SFN:937 SF:5]
[739:247059] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
```

I need to print the lines containing "START" using python ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    for i in lines:
        if i.__contains__("START"):
            print i
```

assuming you have a file.txt that contain data
you can use the following code
Happing coding

Comment: Why are you using `__contains__` instead of `in`?

Answer (score 2):

As a one liner from the command line:

**Code:**

```
python -c "import sys;[sys.stdout.write(l) for l in sys.stdin if ' START ' in l]" < file1
```

**Results:**

```
[739:246050] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
[739:247059] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Stephen Rauch is cool, but I think that you are new to python so here is a basic function.

Considering, "START" must always be at the start of the Message, and not in between like,

```
[739:247021] PHYThrad: START DSPMsgQ  Received: msg type is[130] and SFNSF [14997] [SFN:937 SF:5] # START at second index after split.
```

If we consider the above use case, here is a function which can print `"START"` lines present in the file at the start of the log message.

```
def getStart(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as reader:
        for lines in reader.readlines(): # get list of lines
            start =  lines.split(' ')[1] # Split with space, and check the word is "START"
            if start =='START':
                print lines

getStart("a.txt") # considering your filename is a.txt.
```

---

> Output:

```
[739:246050] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]

[739:247059] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` for this.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sLKG1U/3

```
import re

regex = r"^\[[^\]]*\]\s*(START\b.*)"

test_str = ("[739:246050] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]\n"
"[739:247021] PHYThrad: DSPMsgQ  Received: msg type is[130] and SFNSF [14997] [SFN:937 SF:5]\n"
"[739:247059] START of MACThread:receved msg type[47]")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end =     match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the condition expression `'START' in line` where `line` is the line you want to check.